# Remote control for Icom IC-7100

Tags: remote-control, icom

I just got my new Icom 7100, and while I'd love to operate it locally, there are just too many things near me that get interfered with from RF.

As such, one solution is to remotely control it - I have some suitable QTH's for the transceiver and antennas all of which have access to internet. I can piece a machine together to run windows, linux, whatever is necessary to get this working.

Any software recommendations?

It's nice to note that the 7100 has a usb connection which allows me to obtain two sound interfaces - one "microphone" and one "speaker" on the Icom. I'm not familiar with CAT control, but apparently I can also send commands over USB too.

There is this software Icom makes (RS-BA1), but I would have to wait for it to ship (who the hell still sells CDs of software!?) In addition, I'm sure there are some free and open implementations, I just can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the free-ware DXLab Suite, one component of which -- Commander -- provides transceiver control that supports the IC-7100. However, Commander is not designed for remote control. The two applications most frequently used applications for that purpose are [TRX-Manager](http://www.trx-manager.com/) and [Ham Radio Deluxe](http://www.ham-radio-deluxe.com/) . Neither is free, but both offer a free trial. User reviews are available [here](http://www.eham.net/reviews/detail/680) and [here](http://www.eham.net/reviews/detail/3498).

Comment: If Commander is not designed for the purpose stated by the question, why are you mentioning it?

Comment: At this point I've given up and plan on making my own thing. Why reinvent the wheel you may ask. I'm doing so because all the wheels I know are either poorly documented, closed-source, or require a steep price tag. https://github.com/openham is where you will see the fruits of my work, and do email me at kd2fjb@mit.edu if you have any questions and the like.

Comment: @PhilL As the author of a suite of station automation applications, I have found it necessary to disclose my role when commenting on related topics. I mentioned Commander so readers would understand why I wasn't recommending its usage in this scenario.